# Considering complexity of STL container operations

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Do we factor-in the time/space complexities of STL container operations when calculating the complexity of an algorithm? For example, given the following code snippet:

```
// str is an std::string, and size = str.size()
std::string res;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  // size is some integer
    res += str[i];
```

Is the time complexity of the above code snippet:
O(size) because of the loop?

OR

O(size^2): because in each loop iteration we're appending to an std::string and that is a linear time complexity operation?

If there is no generic answer, I'm asking what do we need to consider when in an interview. Is there a kind of a de-facto convention to consider/ignore STL containers operations' time/space complexities?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Even if the example code doesn't show the complete picture, my question is whether the complexities of STL container operations need to be taken into account in calculating the complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: Appending to a `std::string` is not a linear operation. It is amortized constant.

Comment: From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/, Complexity:
Unspecified, but generally up to linear in the new string length.

Comment: @user1157812 Well that's inaccurate. The `operator+=` overload that takes a `CharT` argument is amortized constant time complexity because `std::string` stores its length and doesn't have to walk to the end every time to append a single character. It'll occasionally have to re-allocate memory and that'll involve copying the existing contents.

Comment: @user1157812: Well that's wrong. It is true that `std::basic_string` is a bit underspecified compared to other containers, but there is no reason for the complexity of its operations to be different from `std::vector`, and I know of no implementation where the complexity of appending single characters is a linear operation, and no reason there should be.

Comment: @Praetorian, even if the example code doesn't show the complete picture, my question is whether the complexities of STL container operations need to be taken into account in calculating the complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: @user1157812 You should never use cplusplus.com: it's full of errors. cppreference.com is the recommended site. And http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D says the complexity of += with a char argument is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to consider the complexity of the individual operations, regardless of whether it happens in your code or inside a library function. In fact, Standard C++ Library specifies the time complexity of operations on its containers, and also the time complexity of its algorithms, in order to make your computations possible.

In your specific example the answer depends on the sizes of individual `str` elements in the array of strings `str[]`. If the length of each element string is roughly `size`, then the answer is O(size<sup>2</sup>). If each element has a fixed size, then the answer is O(size), because the constant length can be factored out of the expression.

Comment: The phrase "sizes of individual str elements" means size of each character in str?

Comment: @user1157812 I did not see the declaration of `str`, so I assumed it's an array of strings. If it's a string, `+=` should be an amortized linear.